# how to play multiple videos one fter the another in xamarin cross platform form c#

Tags: android, ios, .net, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

how to play multiple videos one after the another in xamarin cross platform form c#
I have tried using list, array but the problem is that the last video only gets played, rest videos just doesnt play.

```
        MediaQueue mq = new MediaQueue();
        MediaFile mf = new MediaFile();
        if (PlayStopButtonText.Text == "Play")
        {
     /*string videoUrl1 = "https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4";
         string videoUrl = "https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/e68c/690eebb1-797a-40ef-a841-c63dded4e68c/Cognitive-Services-Emotion_high.mp4";
         CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(videoUrl,MediaFileType.Video,ResourceAvailability.Remote);
            //CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayNext();*/
            mf.Url = videoUrll;
            mf.Type = MediaFileType.Video;
            mq.Insert(0,mf);
            mf.Url = videoUrl;
            mf.Type = MediaFileType.Video;
            mq.Insert(1, mf);
            foreach(var item in mq)
            {
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(item.Url,MediaFileType.Video);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: I have tried making a mediaQueue , array and list to play multiple videos one after the another automatically but only the last video gets played.

Comment: Okay thank you for adding the code. I've up-voted your question. Now we will see if anyone responds. But in future it is best to provide the code immediately because most answers will arrive while the question is still fresh. Regards.

Comment: You want to play multiple videos (continuously) in one player or you have a list of players under each other and start the next if the previous ends?

Comment: i want to play multiple videos one after the another(as soon as one video ends, the another starts) in a single player.